# Minitab 17 Menu Bar not visible

Tags: minitab, minitab-16

Minitab is missing the Menu bar at the top in my PC.Can anyone help me how to restore the Menu Bar?I have not changed any setting to hide it.

[image: MiniTab Menu bar]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Program Files (x86) folder on C: drive and locate Minitab folder. Find and execute rmd.exe

Comment: Thank you very much! I had the exact same problem and now I have my bars again. I am a bit sad that MiniTab has no other way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You may restart it first.

Minitab will initial itself when launched.

And at last you can reinstall it.

Thank you,wish you find it useful.